# how to put search results inside a div using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax

the idea is, I want to put my search results from mysql inside "result_div" without reloading the whole page using ajax. thank you.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id = "search_jo" >
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search_jo'])){
?>
<div class="panel-body" id = "result_div">
<?php
$sql = "some sql statement here";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $db_conn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    // php echo statement here fecthing data from sql
}   
mysql_free_result($result);
?>                                      
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: The idea is, that you try something, and then if you get stuck, you come, and ask a question. Getting stuck at the beginning is not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this `w3school` code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showResult(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
<div id="livesearch"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```